# c# When does System.Drawing.Bitmap decompress the image stream?

Tags: c#, image

Right now I am using System.Drawing.Bitmap to take an image and divide it into regions. I assume that Bitmap must decompress the image in order to perform operations on it.

However, the Bitmap class accepts these formats: BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF

Some of these formats are compressed, so if the data in the stream is compressed, doesn't it have to be decompressed to perform manipulations? If so, does that mean that the Bitmap class allocates more memory for the decompressed version of the stream?

i feel like if the bitmap class makes data modifications to the stream then it would have to decompress the stream which should make the bitmap class take the same amount of memory working with BMP streams as when it works with PNG streams, despite the fact that the PNG streams is smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it does, GDI needs raw pixel data to feed it to the graphic card and/or represent it, so yes, it's being decompressed, but may be you don't see the memory rising because it's done into the system/graphic card.

Some special cases are DXT textures and some other special types which are understood by the hardware and don't need to be decompressed to work.

Comment: ah ok that may be the case. regardless there is no reason I shouldn't keep the stream itself as a PNG stream then and pass that to the constructor, correct? I wanted a copy of a stream, but saving it as bitmap took a lot more memory than saving it as a PNG, yet I didn't see how it could avoid eventually needing memory anyway. However, if it has access to the graphics card that would make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes, indeed it's always a good idea to use PNG instead of BMP, the decompression overhead is little compared to having a big BMP of tens of Mb. But as you said, Bitmaps are really memory consuming resources, is very easy to get thousands of Mb's used in bitmaps if you don't use them carefully, remember to dispose always unused bitmaps, don't let the garbage collector take them, you don't know when they will be collected.